# Can I perform `git pull` without password prompt but `git push` with password prompt?

Tags: git

I have known that I can use SSH protocol in order to perform `git pull` & `git push` without password prompt.

But I want more convenient way.
Could I do `git pull` **without** password prompt but `git push` **with** password prompt?

The reason I want this preference:

1. I want the easiest way to `git pull` code
2. I want the confirmation before I really want to do `git push`

Comment: So you want to protect your code against yourself?

Comment: you can set `cache timeout` in your git config. but it works for both actions (pull/push).

Comment: looks like you want *confirmation*. asking for a password is an overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Change your push & pull remotes to two different urls. If you do `git remote -v` you can change the push url like `git remote set-url --push origin https://github.com/minshallj/wtf.git`

Use a URL you don't have to enter a password for (like `git@...`) and one that requires a password for the push url (like `https://...`)